# How to use CryptUnprotectData in C#

Tags: c#

Could someone provide detailed example of how to use `CryptUnprotectData` method in C#. All the information that I find brings examples in C.

Comment: Stackoverflow is an english Q/A Website.

Comment: Why is this on hold? The Op has provided an English translation?

Comment: Found C# example of the method you mention here: http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If its possible in `C`, just import it:

```
[
DllImport("Crypt32.dll",
SetLastError=true,
CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)
]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CryptUnprotectData(
    ref DATA_BLOB pDataIn,
    StringBuilder szDataDescr,
    ref DATA_BLOB pOptionalEntropy,
    IntPtr pvReserved,
    ref CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT pPromptStruct,
    CryptProtectFlags dwFlags,
    ref DATA_BLOB pDataOut
);
```

From http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/crypt32.cryptunprotectdata

Comment: But i have problems for construct the pDataIn structure in c#